# Swift play sound works in simulator but not IPhone

Tags: swift

I wrote the following code that plays a sound when a button is pressed, it works perfectly on the simulator (IPhone7), but not when running on my IPhone X.  The mute button is not on on my phone.

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{
    var soundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playNote(noteIndex: sender.tag)
    }

    func playNote(noteIndex : Int){
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note\(noteIndex)", withExtension: "wav")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options:[])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:soundURL!)
        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
        soundPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a bug with code like `var soundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!`. Please replace that with `var soundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: No, that did not work.  Thank you though.

Comment: Can you give more info for reproducing the problem? Your code works fine on my device. There must be more to it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the solution:

Go to: File->Project Settings... , change "Derived Data:" to "Project-relative Location", click "Done".

That worked for me.